# Rotation inverts when changed through edit box

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

when using the rotation tool if i change the angle using the edit box the rotation inverts
this started happening yesterday so is it some option to invert?

Comment: Hmmmm.... I tried this as well in 2.92, it smells like s bug. The rotation widget works in "relative" degrees, but when changing it in the mod panel is doing weird stuff! Maybe you should report it as a bug.

Comment: Hello :). This is an annoying bug in 2.92.